# Google Sheets Macro - JS

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get the month of a cell containing a value in this format *(dd/mm/yyyy)*

```
    var date = new Date(scadenziario.getRange(eRow,eCol).getValue());
    var month = date.getMonth();
```

I am not sure why, but it doesn't work.
The cell cointaining the date display this in the sheet: *20/05/2021*
I would like the month variable to be matching the month of the cell, in this case 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date in the cell is not a date object. You can verify that if you run `ISDATE`:

[image]

One way to solve your issue is to use [getDisplayValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue) instead and [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) the relevant part of the resulting string:

```
  const date = scadenziario.getRange(eRow,eCol).getDisplayValue();
  const month = date.slice(3,5).replace("0","");
```

Last but not least, you want to get `5` and not `05` so one way is to get `05` and remove the `0` part. If the date is `12` then you will get the full number `12`.

Comment: You said that the date in the cell is not a date object, so I've assumed that the code was correct and would work if the cell was a date object. I formatted the cell as a date object and it worked. Thank you very much